# Cache validator for Google Webfonts

Tags: caching, optimization, apache2, google-pagespeed, etag

So I'm creating an ultra optimized site, and my page load speed with https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/ is **99 (out of 100)**.

The only thing keeping me away from full hundred is this:

> By specifying a cache validator - a Last-Modified or ETag header - you ensure that the validity of cached resources can efficiently be determined.

What?! I don't know what should I do. How do I set a cache validator for google webfonts?

I've the webfont like this: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`.

I'm on ubuntu with apache2 if that matters.

Downloading the webfont to server and using it from there drops the score to 96 so that won't help either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do anything about it. You can't control what headers google server sends.

I would even go so far as to say it is reporting a false positive that you should fix.

http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffonts.googleapis.com%2Fcss%3Ffamily%3DOpen%2BSans%3A400%2C800

As you can see the resource is cached, has a max age header and is even compressed.

**You site is fast enough!** I wouldn't worry about getting 100. You can probably stop optimizing it.

But if you want to tinker some more, here's a few ideas on improving things, I ran a report: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130703_H7_15KM/

- I would have your server send a [204 No Content header](http://www.phpied.com/204-no-content/) for your non-existent favicon.ico file OR make one and add it so there's no 404 on the resource.
- [Use a CDN](http://www.cdnplanet.com/) for your resources
- [Use progressive jpegs](http://blog.patrickmeenan.com/2013/06/progressive-jpegs-ftw.html) and optimize the ones you're using

Comment: I actually have a favicon, and jQuery is loaded from google. I don't like jpgs but I have optimized pngs :)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a nice and clean solution.**

That 99 score is really good. However, if you are concerned about that remaining 1 score, you can load Open Sans font from Easy Fonts library that fixes this issue.

```
<link href="https://pagecdn.io/lib/easyfonts/open-sans.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Complete fonts reference is available on [Easy Fonts](https://pagecdn.com/lib/easyfonts) website. There are several more benefits of using Easy Fonts library in production. See this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073920/369005.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy you can with `<link rel="prefetch" type="text/css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" href="fonturl">`

Comment: Any info on why this works &/or where this is documented?

Comment: It works, i know about this but only in chrome from what i know.

Comment: What is this? What does it do? Thanks