# Google fonts loading optimisation and caching

Tags: html, fonts, pagespeed, google-font-api, google-fonts

Google's page speed test shows only one problem:

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>   Your page has 1 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
>   None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
>   Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400

The fonts being loaded as fonts.google.com recommends:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

Within `<head />` tag.

As far as i know, there is no way to control google's fonts caching and also, this url's output depends on user agent, so it doesn't make sense to distribute the fonts locally. So, the question is: what do i suppose to do with that? How do i satisfy google's speed test?

Comment: Have you seen this lib https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader? Maybe it can help you - google fonts example is the first in the "get started" section.

Comment: Have you tested with the @import method? This could be more efficient for your application - it did explicitly ping 'above-the-fold content'. If not, something else may be at play here; please show more of this page's code.

Comment: Apparently no one knows how to use style tag.

Comment: I am not sure, but IMHO the warning message is dealing with the position of <link> tag. You can place it before the ending </body> and the warning dissmiss. But you will have rendering flash after loading the site.

Comment: Cacheable Google Fonts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073920/369005

Answer (score 1):

So far i know ist the best solution today if you use [Fontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader). It loads first a short .js script and late the font async.
Tipp: `Use font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans serif';` async has the problem the font type is switching after the site is rendered. So the user see a short font switch like a flash. If you use sans serif as fallback the switch is not so big.
Or use `.wf-active`

Comment: Keep in mind: https://fonts.gstatic.com/xxx is cached by many browser for months. https://fonts.googleapis.com/xxx only for 24h to fast support of font changes.

Answer (score 1):

`data:font` with fallback needed, load on footer. That will give result like mine :

[image: base64 encoded font]

This is example CSS for fallback, else may fail on some device :

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Arial'; /* Do Proper Naming */
 src: url('Arial.eot'); /* For IE 5-8 */
 src: local('?'), /* It is called smile hack to promote CSS to UTF-16 */
 url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,) format('truetype'), /*base64 encoded font IE9, Safari 3.1+ FF 3.5+ Chrome 4.0+*/
 url('Arial.svg#123XYZ') format('svg'); /* iPad, iPhone with OS less than or equal to 4.1 */
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

I wrote that -- https://thecustomizewindows.com/2013/10/base64-encoding-and-font-css/ That CSS is from an expert developer whom I paid, font developer. Read my guide, test that website's source code, use in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess loading fonts asynchronously can resolve the issue. I found an interesting article, may be it can help you [font loading asynchronously](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462209/Using-custom-font-without-slowing-down-page-load).

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot control Googles headers (including expiration headers), I can see only one solution – download these two stylesheets and fonts to your own hosting server, change HTML tags accordingly.

Then, you can set expiration headers as you wish.

```html
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/0eC6fl06luXEYWpBSJvXCBJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/Fl4y0QdOxyyTHEGMXX8kcRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/-L14Jk06m6pUHB-5mXQQnRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/I3S1wsgSg9YCurV6PUkTORJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/NYDWBdD4gIq26G5XYbHsFBJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/Pru33qjShpZSmG3z6VYwnRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/ek4gzZ-GeXAPcSbHtCeQI_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/mErvLBYg_cXG3rLvUsKT_fesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/-2n2p-_Y08sg57CNWQfKNvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/u0TOpm082MNkS5K0Q4rhqvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/NdF9MtnOpLzo-noMoG0miPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/Fcx7Wwv8OzT71A3E1XOAjvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/CWB0XYA8bzo0kSThX0UTuA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

Download this .woff2 file and save it anywhere on your webserver. Copy & paste this piece of stylesheet into any of your own CSS files or HTML. Change the link from https://fonts.googleapis.com to your new URL.

Comment: Don't do it. This files type are depending on the browser and his font support. There a four fonts type the system switch depending on the browser.

Comment: Sorry today are five fonts types: WOFF, OTF, TTF, SVG, EOT

Comment: This answer is copied almost verbatim from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29091105/2838033

Answer (score 0):

Locally hosting the css and fonts speeds up a site by a significant margin -- at least for the "initial page load" view as calculated by [pagespeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/).

IMHO its not the CDN but the CSS generation. Googlefonts seems to be running a script to generate the unique CSS for the user's browser. Im guessing its swamped by constant traffic and, or written in php.  Lol kidding its 2023 it's gotta be node.

Woff has a [100% Browser Compatibility Score](https://www.lambdatest.com/web-technologies/woff) as of 2023-03-20 therefore using woff at this point by itself *should* be fine. The existence of 5 different font formats regardless. Woff2 has a 92 score with low support for IE.

Lacking an IE 11 browser file use the following User-Agent string in curl or other url agent to obtain the css with a link to the woff file.

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Or use [google-webfonts-helper](https://gwfh.mranftl.com/fonts) that makes the download job easy.