# Testing using gtmetrix.com in YSLOW shows far-future expiration error

Tags: html, css, yslow, load-time

When I am testing the site using gtmetrix.com in YSLOW, it shows this message. I don't know how to add expire headers.

> There are 2 static components without a far-future expiration date.
>
> http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic
> http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900

How can it be solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I 'leverage browser caching' for Google fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091014/how-do-i-leverage-browser-caching-for-google-fonts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change the cache expiry headers on these external resources, as you're not in control of the server they're hosted on.

If you want to fix this, you could [self-host these webfonts](https://dev.to/kelli/how-to-self-host-google-fonts-on-your-own-server-d4i) and do a little research on how to set cache headers on them for your type of server (Apache? nginx? Information should be readily available on Google or from your web hosting company if you use one).

Personally, I recommend taking these sorts of metrics with a pinch of salt. [Even gtmetrix.com doesn't score perfectly](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/gtmetrix.com/VxqDbjuN) by their own standards. Their worst score is also for the cache settings of google-hosted services.